# How do I execute multiple function within another function?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In **Minecraft 1.13.2 Java**

I want to execute multiple functions (from function files).

To be executed is a series of circle ploting in order to create a circular tower.

The code for the circle:05 function file is working as expected ingame. It clones the block from underneath the executer to plot a circle around @s then teleport @s 1 block over.

**circle:05**

```
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~-5 ~ ~0
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~-4 ~ ~-3
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~-4 ~ ~-2
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~-4 ~ ~-1
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~-4 ~ ~1
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~-4 ~ ~2
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~-4 ~ ~3
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~-3 ~ ~-4
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~-3 ~ ~-3
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~-3 ~ ~3
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~-3 ~ ~4
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~-2 ~ ~-4
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~-2 ~ ~4
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~-1 ~ ~-4
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~-1 ~ ~4
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~0 ~ ~-5
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~0 ~ ~5
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~1 ~ ~-4
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~1 ~ ~4
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~2 ~ ~-4
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~2 ~ ~4
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~3 ~ ~-4
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~3 ~ ~-3
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~3 ~ ~3
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~3 ~ ~4
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~4 ~ ~-3
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~4 ~ ~-2
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~4 ~ ~-1
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~4 ~ ~1
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~4 ~ ~2
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~4 ~ ~3
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~5 ~ ~0
clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~ ~
tp ~ ~1 ~
```

My problem is to execute multiple times this function (circles:05)

I tried with basic code line writing `function circles:05`, then `execute as @s ~ ~ ~ run function circles:05` but nothing works.

**maketower**

```
execute as @s run function circles:05
execute as @s run function circles:05
execute as @s run function circles:05
execute as @s run function circles:05
```

Both files are in the correct folder, available within the ingame command-line but the result is not working because @s seems to falls down on previous block after `/tp`.

Any clue on how to make this work / the console command to fly?

Comment: Is this Google translated? The answer to the title is "press either space or F3+N twice", but the question text is something about functions and cloning. Also, the tags you mentioned don't exist and they would be confusing (and therefore deleted) if they existed. You also seem to want to execute a function multiple times, but somehow it doesn't work? Why?

Comment: Hello @FabianRöling , well, no it is not google.translated but feel free to correct my english if it can make more fluid. I will modify title for a better up to the point one. I want the /console command to fly. Also, there is a significant difference inbetween 1.13 and previous to 1.13 versions of minecraft, is why i suggested a tag creation.

So, yes, execute a function a number of times but it does not work. I suspect because @s is falling back on block instead of beeing teleported 1 block upper.

Comment: Your function might not be working because a command is typed wrong. The tp command at the end catches my eye because you did not specify who to tp. Use "tp @s ~ ~1 ~" and see if that works? If the function is valid you should be able to type /function then the tab key, and the function name should come up.

Comment: TY @SpiceWeasel for your comment. In Java and Bedrock edition, the <target> can be omited and defaulted to 'self'. See : https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/teleport . 

I gave your suggestion a try, but no result.

Comment: As yes, I have forgotten. What about in your datapack folder? Is your pack.mcmeta correctly formatted? Does your function have an ANSI text format?
EDIT: No wait, that can't be it, just remembered you said everything there was orderly. Do you have to use the execute commands for all those clone commands?

Comment: @SpiceWeasel Both files are in the correct folder, available within the ingame command-line but the result is not working because @s seems to falls down on previous block after /tp. I can run the cercles:05 function and it works as expected. But when i run the 'maketower' function, it 'seem to' execute cercles:05 only once.

Comment: @MilchePatern I'm going to copy your function into one of my worlds and see if I can fix this.

Comment: @MilchePatern Hang tight, I'm on to something here...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a clue on why this isn't working. It should, and I've tried all the tricks I know. My suggestion? Get rid of that function and copy the entire set of commands four times, but with one addition - use

```
execute as @a[tag=tower] at @s run clone <x> <y> <z>
```

When you just want that circle, use the function. If you want the tower, tag yourself with "tower" and run the same function.

Sorry, that's all I got. This could be a bug or a removed feature to use the function command within other functions (which I doubt). I'll tell you if I find the real answer later.

Comment: Thank you, but your suggestion of copying the entire set of commands will not work for me, i am doing this so i can create towers of different radius and height. I will give a try with "execute as @a[tag=tower] at @s run clone...".

Post edit : we have progress

Comment: Ooh, I have an answer to that problem. It will let you create a cylinder that is fully customize-able, from what kind of blocks it uses to how long it is to how big the radius is. Would you like me to tell you on how to do that with just one function? (it's very complex)
EDIT: On second thought it's not only very complex but it can also get very laggy, and I don't know how much use you'll be able to get out of it. Perhaps it would be best if I keep helping you with the original answer?

Comment: Post edit : we have progress with 'execute as @s .. at @s .. "  I could run the 4 functions .. I come back to you later with progres ... !!!

Comment: @MilchePatern Oh, so did you figure it out?

Comment: i have to read about 'execute' command .. i now think it was a relativity issue since all the inner functions were executed at the same origin. 'execute as @s at @s ... ' fixed my thing. Now, i am on a good way to self answer this. ;)

Comment: Remarkable. I tried that trick and it didn't work! I'm glad you found the solution though. Congratulations!

Answer (score 1):

I may be late, but you can't expect the player to teleport as soon as you execute the `tp` command. Minecraft runs on a tick system, where everything is done inside of a single game-tick (1/20 seconds).

The player's position is only updated at the end of every game-tick, so executing the `tp` command only queues the teleport until all the next commands are done. You can see this by writing some say blocks in the function, since this proves that `circles:05` is indeed being executed 5 times, but the player's location is only being updated once every command for that game tick is done.

That's all well and good but how could you fix this? We need create a `for` loop using a function with the `tick` tag ([more info here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tag)). This tag will cause a command to be executed in quick succession. Next we need to create a scoreboard that will work as our increment variable, call it `circles_i` for example.

Now edit `circles:05` so that before every `clone` command, there's an `execute if score @s circles_i matches 0..5 run`. For example:

```
execute if score @s circles_i matches 0..5 run clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~-5 ~ ~0
```

Finally, at the end of the function, add a new command:

```
scoreboard players remove @s circles_i 1
```

to decrement the scoreboard

Now, in the `maketower` function, set the score for `circles_i` to be 5 (or however tall you want it to be):

```
scoreboard players set @s circles_i 5
```

This should execute the `circles:05` function 5 times, once each game tick, elapsing a quarter of a second total. Unfortunately this is the fastest way to do this with predictable results

Comment: Actually, you can tp multiple times within a single tick. The reason it is probably not working for you is because you are missing `execute at @s` before the tp command. If you don't use this execute command, the command thinks you are still at your previous location (before teleport).

Answer (score 1):

Set up a dummy objective called count. Insert this before your tp command.

```
scoreboard players remove @s count 1
```

Replace your `tp ~~~1` with `execute positioned ~~~1 run function namespace:make_circle`.

In a tick function, write this:

```
execute as @a[scores={count=1..}] at @s run function namespace:make_circle
```

Now that you just need to set your score count to an integer and you can build a tower of the same height as the integer you put in.