# How do I make a player fly using the console command line?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

**In Minecraft 1.13.2 PC JAVA creative mode**

What is (is there a) console command to fly in creative mode?

The basic 'in game' option is to double-tap spacebar. I am looking for a console /command line in order to use it within function files.

This question is a split from [How do I execute multiple function within another function?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/342197/ho-do-i-execute-multiple-function-within-another-function/342230) for disambiguation where i thought the problem was a 'flying' issue. User @Fabian Röling already answered but as OP got more precised, his answer seamed inapropriate.

*Asside* : i've seen documentation about Effect but can't figure out how to apply on player @s. Here [minecraft.wiki/w/Status_effect#Levitation](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Status_effect#Levitation)

Comment: Are there any restrictions? Do you want the player to fly upward, walk around and stuff or do you want him to fly more like Super-Man?

Comment: levitate would be good. Flying but not moving?

Comment: So you just want to go straight up and down?

Comment: @SpiceWeasel if i do /tp ~ ~3 ~  .. i want player to remain and not fall back. Asside, is player jumps or crouches, go ... yeah.

Comment: You could give yourself levitation to the 255th interger with /effect give @p levitation <amount of seconds> 255. That prevents players from falling. Would that be what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3):

There is no command to make a player fly, but since you can not not fly in Spectator mode, you can just do this:

```
/gamemode spectator <player>
/gamemode creative <player>
```

If you want the opposite, you can shortly put someone into Survival or Adventure mode and instantly back into Creative mode:

```
/gamemode survival <player>
/gamemode creative <player>
```

Comment: miss "console command to fly in creative mode"